# Arc node topology in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-9.3, topology

I would like to implement an arc node topology in arcmap. Do you know how can i build node topology from line layer in ArcMap 9.3.1?

Comment: Have you Read Their Fine Manual ?  http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//006200000002000000.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 9.3.1 the PDF Poster explains it well:

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/pdf/Topology_rules_poster.pdf

You must use a Personal or File Geodatabase to create the topology rules.

Tip: Clean and Build are in ArcCatalog (use properties to find it on the feature)

Starting Point:
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_topology_in_ArcGIS