# How to make list of nodes at end points of polylines that connect them to others using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geometric-network

I have a sewer network represented as a connected pipelines in a GIS shapefile.

the network is very close to a tree graph that each node is only connected with one or two nodes.

I need to reconstruct the layout of this network on another program.

I first used vertices to points feature to specify the start and the end point of each line.

However, this doesn't help too much because I need to specify which node is connected to which node and the feature of the line that is connecting these two nodes like its diameter or its FID for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this. You could [build a coverage dataset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001300000063000000), it's attribute table will store the logic of the network. You could download [ArcHydro](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/hydro/01vn00000010000000.htm) and this too will extract out the logical network.

For the record you should always mention which license version of ArcGIS you have as this dictates the solution.

Comment: @naaeemmohammad 10.2.2 is the version and ArcMap is the application that you are using.  Your license level will be Basic, Standard or Advanced.

Comment: I was surprised to see a coverage being proposed here - do you think they still have a role to play?  I noticed an answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/1748 which seems to be describing the geodatabase equivalent.

Comment: Just old school I guess! As I understood he just needed a way of extracting the logical connectivity and coverages is just one way. A Geodatabase approach is just as sensible.

Comment: I am really new to gis so I am wondering how to use build coverage I read the help page but it just a description there is no steps on how to apply the coverage so can you please explain how to use the coverage

Comment: For someone new to GIS I think you will be better to focus on Geodatabase Topology and Geometric Networks than Coverages which are from the old Esri architecture that began to be superseded from the mid-late 1990s.

Comment: You could build a network and get the junctions... I too think a coverage would be a bit too advanced @PolyGeo but would also be a nice solution - with FNode#, TNode# detailing connections for each line. If the points are projected you can use Collect Events to concentrate multiple points into a single point but I think the junctions from a network would be the easiest.